# jpql native query not setting parameter

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, jpql, spring-data-jpa

```
@Repository
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, String> {    
//Other queries....

@Query(value = "with cte(group_id, parent_group_id, group_name) as( "
        + "select group_id, parent_group_id, group_name "
            + "from hea.hea_group "
                + "where group_id = ?1 "
        + "union all "
        + "select g.group_id, g.parent_group_id, g.group_name "
            + "from hea.hea_group g "
            + "inner join cte on cte.group_id = g.parent_group_id "
                + "where g.parent_group_id is not null "
        + ") select * from cte", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object> getChildGroups(String groupId);
}
```

Above is the query that I have written that should return the parent group and all of its children. The query does what it is suppose to do when I replace the ?1 with a hard coded group id value and change the method to have no parameters, but when I try to run it as above it returns nothing even though I'm passing in the exact same value that I was hard coding.

Below is the sql that is being generated by the query. When I replace the ? with a group id an run it on a test database it returns the results that it should.

```
    with cte(group_id, parent_group_id, group_name) as( select
    group_id,
    parent_group_id,
    group_name 
from
    hea.hea_group 
where
    group_id = ? 
union
all select
    g.group_id,
    g.parent_group_id,
    g.group_name 
from
    hea.hea_group g 
inner join
    cte 
        on cte.group_id = g.parent_group_id 
where
    g.parent_group_id is not null ) select
    * 
from
    cte
```

Comment: Check the SQL that is issued by JPA.  This is usually done by turning on logging for your JPA provider.

Comment: I added the SQL to the question, I don't see anything wrong with it, it seems to know that group_id is a variable.

Comment: how do you set parameter? Please add the code as well.

Answer (score -2):

The variables are zero based so  ?0 is what you should use.